# Input field and React where Input field is not editable because of react id in attr

Tags: reactjs

I have a specific need to only make one input field in a form (legacy code) a react component. So, I wrap the input with a div and render into it the 'new' input field that needs some special behavior.

The problem arises because the input field is no longer editable. I try to type into it.. nothing. I narrowed it down to the following:

```
 <input type="text" **data-reactid=".2.0.0.0.1.0.0.1.2.0"**
```

When I remove that "data-reactid....", by editing via console, it works.

So when I am using react to sub out one form input field with a react one, it doesn't work unless I manually remove that data-reactid..

Is there a workaround for this, or a reason why this is happening?

Comment: Could you please edit your question with the JSX or JS that you are using to render this `input` on the page?

Comment: Having this exact same problem. Tried setting readonly=false on the input element as well and still no dice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well its just a data attribute written by react to help them render into the DOM more efficiently so it should have no real impact on a input element or any element (unless there is code or style explicitly disabling the input) - I realize that this is no real help - because it happens to you, but this is not typical of react apps with inputs or element with data-attributes.

But if its the only bit of react on the page then that id is a bit long and I would have expected something like ".0" or ".0.0" if its wrapped in a div that react controls.

The react-id is only used by the React engine to work out what elements of the DOM need to be re-written when there are changes to state or props in your components.

One thing I noticed is, typically there would be an ID or in react a ref that you applied to the input in order to interact with it (such as getting its value).

I include the mark-up from a simple entry box on the user login form of a working app, as you can see it's not significantly different from what you have and works on all browsers Windows and Mac down to IE8 included.. (but not any IE below 8) and you need various shims for getting it work on IE8.

```
<input class="username-text-field" id="user-id" type="text" data-reactid=".0.0.0.1.3.0.0.2">
```

If none of these apply or you have them covered then practicably here should be no reason why your input should be disabled. It should just act like any other input. Have tried just dropping you component onto a simple HTML page with only the input on it, just to debug through the component in isolation?

That said,

It does feel that loading the entire React engine and wiring up a component to allow a single input field is a little over-kill. I realize that you're trying not to have to recreate exactly the same functionality you already have in react again on the legacy form, but if your render function is not too onerous then maybe a simple bit of JavaScript or JQuery might be the answer as a one off in the legacy solution (rather than the hit for the library) - just a thought